# Different div Contents overlap on browser resize

Tags: html, css

On re-sizing the browser the div elements overlap each other.

The html file is present at below url:- 
Please help.
http://codepen.io/SanjeetSk/pen/ZQBBaz

Please do not suggest min-width and overflow hidden type of answers.
I am looking for the real solution that is associated with this page and not the workaround. That is why the codepen link is present with this post.
once again
http://codepen.io/SanjeetSk/pen/ZQBBaz

```css
.home-area, .work-area, .contact-area {
padding: 80px 20px 80px 20px;
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
/* overflow: hidden; */
}

.navbar-toggle{
  width: 42px;
  height: 38px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-toggle * {
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-toggle span {
 width: 20px;
 height: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 background-color: green;
 display: block;
}

/* Codepen styling, not required for use */
.navbar-toggle span.bar1 {
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform-origin: 1px 3px;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 1px 3px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 1px 3px;
  -o-transform-origin: 1px 3px;
 transform-origin: 1px 3px;
 width: 24px;
} 
.navbar-toggle span.bar2 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(0);
  -o-transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(0);
  transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(0);
}
.navbar-toggle span.bar3 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0);
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0);
} 
.navbar-toggle span.bar4 {
 -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform-origin: 2px 0px;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 2px 0px;
 transform-origin: 2px 0px;
 width: 24px;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed span.bar1,
.navbar-toggle.collapsed span.bar2,
.navbar-toggle.collapsed span.bar3,
.navbar-toggle.collapsed span.bar4 {
 -ms-transform: none;
 -webkit-transform: none;
 transform: none;
 width: 20px;
}
.footer{
height: 50px;
background-color: #ffc04c;
}
.copyright{
   padding-top: 10px 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Designed and Developed by DigitalSrishti inc -->
  <!--  DigitalSrishti :- Your Digital partner for sustainable future -->
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bs-dos-nav " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-toggle collapsed target" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" id="rotate">
          <span class="bar1"></span>
          <span class="bar2"></span>
          <span class="bar3"></span>
          <span class="bar4"></span>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Your Logo</a>
      </div>
      <nav id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-navigation text-uppercase ">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
          <li class="disabled"><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <a href = "_http://themes.getbootstrap.com/products/application"> click here I liked the friends and enemy :-) profile</a> -->
  <!-- Start Home -->
  <div id="home">
    <div class="home-area">
      <div class="container">
        <h1><strong>Sanjeet Shukla</strong></h1>
        <p>Have a look at some <strong>Works</strong> I have done so far, it <strong>BI Designer</strong> creating modern and responsive reports for <strong>Web</strong> and <strong>Mobile</strong>. You can view my<strong>Profile</strong> and <strong>resume</strong>          and also find a link to become my friend or enemy on social sites, it is cool.. right?</br> Let us work together. Thank you.</p>
        <a href="#work" class="btn btn-default">Let's Begin</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Home -->

  <!-- Start Work -->
  <div id="work">
    <div class="work-area">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>My <strong>Work</strong></h1> Have a look at some of my <strong>Works</strong> It may help you choose best partner for your work ;-)
        <diV class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Mobile Dict</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>HTML Template</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>tic-toe Game</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Pathshala(ERP)</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--         <diV class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Mobile Dict</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>HTML Template</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>tic-toe Game</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Pathshala(ERP)</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
          </div>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Work -->

  <!-- Start Contact -->
  <div id="contact">
    <div class="contact-area">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Contact <strong>Me</strong></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End Contact-->

  <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer" align="center">
    
  <div class="copyright p">© 2016 <a href="www.sanjeetshukla.me">Sanjeet Shukla</a></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: different text are getting ovelapped while we shrink the browser size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set height for -area divs to 100% of browser window and texts no longer fit in the specified container size on browser resize:

```
.home-area, .work-area, .contact-area {
...
height: 100vh;
...
}
```

Use `min-height: 100vh` instead to expand past container height if needed.

Comment: it was a great help, I am learning these things now, so please don't mind if it seems stupid mistake. :-)